# Convert KVM VM with multiple drives to Hyper-V (or somehow clone into a single drive system?)

Tags: hyper-v, kvm-virtualization, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I know this is going to sound weird. I have a VM running under KVM on Centos 6 that ran out of disk space, so 2 qcow2 drives were added, with one of them extending the vg_svn-lv_root LVM VG, and the other as /home/mysql:

`Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_svn-lv_root
                      9.9G  5.7G  3.8G  60% /
tmpfs                 1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/vda1             485M  136M  324M  30% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_svn-lv_home
                      124G   95G   23G  81% /home
/dev/vdb1              50G   43G  4.4G  91% /home/mysql`

The underlying hardware that this VM is running on is showing its age, and this is the only VM running on the server. I want to move it somewhere else, but after a lot of research, I'm still at a loss as to the best way to do it. We have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V machine that has the available capacity, and there are ways to convert qcow2 to vhd, but I don't see any way to do the conversion when there are multiple drives like this.

Do you see a way out of my dilemna?

Comment: Isn't reinstalling the VM and copying the data over an option because it seems like the cleanest solution.

Comment: If I have to go that route, I will. But there is so much legacy stuff on this server that redoing it would be fraught with peril. And I need to keep downtime to a minimum. This server is our git server, our jira server, our confluence server...

Comment: So you can set up the new VM on the new host while this one is running and switch over when you are done. Especially with legacy stuff it's a good way to clean up.